# Datepicker not inside the modal

Tags: javascript, datepicker, modal-dialog

[image]

Why is date picker outside the modal when I clicked the date field?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this? I think `form-group` needs `position:relative`

Comment: awww I don't know fiddle :(

Comment: i tried your suggestion. it didn't work

Comment: @user5572354 Good chance to learn it. It's very simple problem, quite obvious solution, but it requires to see markup for this, not the image.

Comment: @user5572354, a link where we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: increase z-index of the calender and it will start working, but one more thing do you have more then one calender control on the same page?

Comment: increase the z-index. it's lesser then your pup up model window.

Comment: it's working now. thank you so much :)

Comment: <style>
    .datepicker{
        z-index:10000!important;
    }
</style>